# How to Block android apps to show my site?

Tags: php, javascript, android, .htaccess

I have found that certain android applications show my site, I think they use with webview, 
How do I block all applications that can show my site ?

Comment: Do you want to block these apps specifically or mobile devices in whole?

Comment: I certainly did not want to block access to the site via browsers, 
I want to block a specific applications and I want to block other applications try to do it in the future

Answer (score 1):

> How do I block all applications that can show my site ?

You have no means of conclusively determining what software is sending the HTTP request, and Web browsers are "applications". So, either take down your site, which will "block all applications that can show [your] site", or do not worry about what "applications" the user has chosen to view your site.

Comment: in IFAME i can place this in my site: 
<script>if(self != top) { top.location = self.location; }</script>
There is one i can use to block when android application show my site ?

Comment: @motioz: A Web browser *is* an application. I repeat: **a Web browser is an application**. You cannot block all applications without blocking all Web browsers. Any application can implement whatever is necessary to get past any script-kiddie defense, because if a Web browser can do it, any other application can do it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a 100% secure way of doing this. What you can do is to attach a header property to your app browser with a server-validated key. Without this key, in combination with a [mobile browser detection library](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/php_index.php) you'll know if the app is authorized or not.

But if a developer acquire this key there is no prevention for him to implement it. Also detecting a mobile browser is not an exact science.

Comment: How do I block all applications that can show my site? i want to keep users can get to my site only via browsers

Comment: Like I said, its not an exact science. But you could use the lib I linked to or maybe something a bit more lightweight as http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ to detect a mobile browser.

Comment: I understand, but the User Agent is the same when a user come from a regular browser or view the site in a application

Comment: Your comment question was "How do I block all applications that can show my site".